# Finding an active object unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the track divided (5-6) parts with same tag and all these track parts have the same script individually attached to each of them.When the track part becomes invisible since it has its z value continuously being changed in order to give impression of car being running ,

```
void OnBecameInvisible ()
        {
this.transform.position = new Vector3 (this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y, 32.6f);
        }
```

I do this in order to get it back ahead on screen. I want to know which part of road my car is on.How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have colliders attached to your car and road segments? If so then attach a rigidbody to your car and set is trigger to true and check it like that

Comment: @actually for some reason, it has to be some pixels above the surface of road and not exactly on the surface.I tried using bounds.intersect and colliders, but for this reason, they wouldnot work

Comment: Can you post a YouTube video or some screenshots so we can understand what you are attempting to achieve... At this point I am unsure of how it is designed and therefore can't help you any further.